# How to select object by another object's field

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a 2 entity - **Klient** and **DocAcc**. For access to my data I use Spring Data. Here is my repository:

```
public interface DocAccRepository extends CrudRepository<DocAcc, Long> {
    @Query("select d from DocAcc d where d.sals = klient.sals")
    List<DocAcc> findByKlient(Klient klient);
}
```

this code didn't work. Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'klient.sals' [select d from vap.entity.DocAcc d where d.sals = klient.sals]
```

My entity wired more than one field. How can I acces to object parameters inside Query?

Comment: It would be better if you could post `Kient` and `DocAcc` entity fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SpEL expressions in @Query

```
public interface DocAccRepository extends CrudRepository<DocAcc, Long> {
    @Query("select d from DocAcc d where d.sals = :#{#klient.sals}")
    List<DocAcc> findByKlient(@Param("klient") Klient klient);
}
```

More info here: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions